# It is possible to use Time series to predict wether a marketing action is a success or not

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis, marketing

Is it possible to use time series could be used to forecast the implementation of an offer ?
Following I am describing an example about how to implement that, is it valid?
Can I use ARIMA time series for this?

First of all, the use of time series could be seen as a prediction. It is a benchmark between the a good segmentation of a promotional action vs. the traditional way of sending generic offers to the entire population of customers.

For example, only send excellent promotions related with winter clothes for those customer who effectively lives in cold regions and bought in the past warm clothing.

Therefore, the comparison should be between the actions of the entirely population who used to received a promo email, vs the reaction of specific segment of customers.

Comment: Look into intervention analysis, search this site.